# Hibernate detached queries as a part of the criteria query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql, criteria

java experts can you please help me write detached queries as a part of the criteria query for the following SQL statement.

```
select A.*
FROM AETABLE A
where not exists
(
    select entryid
    FROM AETABLE B
    where B.classpk = A.classpk
    and B.userid = A.userid
    and B.modifiedDate > A.modifiedDate
)
and userid = 10146
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to write a [correlated subquery](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-detachedqueries). Assuming property / class names match column / table names above:

```
DetachedCriteria subquery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(AETable.class, "b")
 .add(Property.forName("b.classpk").eqProperty("a.classpk"))
 .add(Property.forName("b.userid").eqProperty("a.userid"))
 .add(Property.forName("b.modifiedDate").gtProperty("a.modifiedDate"));

Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(AETable.class, "a")
 .add(Property.forName("userid").eq(new Integer(10146)))
 .add(Subqueries.notExists(subquery);
```

Answer (score 6):

Just one addition to the above query. If the entryid is not the primary key, then you'll need to add projection.

```
DetachedCriteria subquery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(AETable.class, "b")
 .add(Property.forName("b.classpk").eqProperty("a.classpk"))
 .add(Property.forName("b.userid").eqProperty("a.userid"))
 .add(Property.forName("b.modifiedDate").gtProperty("a.modifiedDate"))
 .add(setProjection(Projections.property("entryId"));  // Additional projection property

Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(AETable.class, "a")
 .add(Property.forName("userid").eq(new Integer(10146)))
 .add(Subqueries.notExists(subquery);
```

Comment: I was doing something very similar and needed the projection.